# What is the best Layout to be used While designing for multiple screens and for both landscape and portrait

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: Android Layout Buttons]

Hello! I have just started playing with android layouts and i wonder if there is a general way of applying basic layout so that it will adjust itself to multiple screens and automatically to landscape view. For example:
 In the picture above, I have added some buttons. Now what i want to learn is which layout or options(like weight,gravity,alignment) to b used so that they remain the same in Every view & on every screen. Some says to use linear layout within linear and then add weight and alignment. They said that by doing this, you have flexibility to remove any button and yet no other button looses its place(unlike in relative layout). Can there be better way that will have same layout on all screens and yet flexible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RelativeLayout is very easy to use and if you learn to align the widgets in it, the layout will look the same on every screen BUT it's good for a layout that is very simple (few widgets on layout) or a layout that you know that will never change because changing on RelativeLayout is so hard and the best way is editing the XML not working on DesignView.

LinearLayout is not flexible like RelativeLayout but making change in it is so simple and other widgets will not lose their positions.

After all if you want to design layout for multiple screen size I recommend to use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple linear layouts if you want to create a FORM.
otherwise Absolute layout is also good but not much preferable.

Relative layout needs practice, as you have to set widgets with respect to other.

multiple linear layouts may be useful.